# Plot grey encoding

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to draw a grey constellation on a panel, as shown below.

[image]

Till now I have a list that stores the [grey encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code). The list stores a symbol object that draws an ellipse (constellation) and takes three parameters... x and y locations and the grey code when constructed.

I need to draw the whole list on a panel. The list has to be traversed and each sybmol must be drawn on the panel. E.g. for 16 symbol.  The first symbol will be draw in location 0 , 0 and y is incremented until the fourth symbol. Then xOffset has to be shifted to the right so that the fifth symbol is drawn on the right of the fourth.  Then the sixth above the fifth and so on...  In general they have to be drawn like a sine wave..

```
        sb.SetLocation(x, y);
        gh.Controls.Add(sb);

        if (gh.Controls.Count % 4 == 0) { x += sb.Width; }
        y += sb.Height;
```

sb is an instance of Symbol class..
The above code is draws the first four symbols but and then shifts the x but then I need to draw the symbol bottom up.. i need somehow to switch between (y += sb.Height) and (y -= sb.Height) and change X offset when the MODULO is 0..Any ideas how can I do this please. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *grey constellation*, *grey encoding* and *grey code*? Could you add an image the illustrates what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code

Comment: Image added.. note the list how is being plotted

Comment: Note that "gray code" is not named after the color "gray" and thus is not subject to language changes such as "grey color" in English. It is named after Frank Gray, and is thus *always* named "gray code". Please don't confuse people by specifying "grey code" and hoping they understand what you mean.

Comment: Please show your full code and the values of `x` and `y` you're getting and what you want them to become instead.

Answer (score 0):

define a variable somewhere to hold your operation (+ or -)

```
bool sign=true;
```

then while plotting switch like this

```
if (gh.Controls.Count+4 % 8 == 0) sign = false;
if (gh.Controls.Count % 8 == 0) sign = true;

if (sign && gh.Control.Count % 4 != 0) y+= sb.height;
if (!sign && gh.Control.Count % 4 != 0) y -= sb.heighht;
```

this gives you the pattern :

**Count** / **y value**

1 / +

2/ +

3/ +

4/ the same

5/ -

6/ -

7/ -

8/ the same

.

.

.